# Creating a partition with sfdisk

Tags: partitioning, mount, sd-card

I am working on a lab which needs me to format an SD card with two partitions. I have formatted the SD card, discovered it as sde1 and then i ran `sudo umount /dev/sde1` before running:

```
sudo sfdisk /dev/sde1 << EOF
> 1,,0xE,*
> EOF
```

I get the following error:

```
Checking that no-one is using this disk right now ... FAILED

This disk is currently in use - repartitioning is probably a bad idea.
Umount all file systems, and swapoff all swap partitions on this disk.
Use the --no-reread flag to suppress this check.

sfdisk: Use the --force flag to overrule all checks.
```

I have no idea where to go from here. I am new to this as well. I had read that I needed to disable automount on Ubuntu and used `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount false` which had not effect. I would still get the above error. Please help.

Comment: What does `sudo lsof | grep /dev/sde` show?

Comment: `sudo lsof | grep /dev/sde`
`lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.`

Comment: Hmmm...can you create a new disk label with `gparted`? What about `Gnome Disks`?

Comment: Give me some time to try that. Just fyi the lab had the following steps:

    `Now type the below command to partition the micro-SD card
(we assume that the card is seen as '/dev/mmcblk0'):  
  
sudo sfdisk /dev/mmcblk0 << EOF  
1,,0xE,*  
EOF  
  
Remove the SD card and insert it again (to make sure new
partitions are detected properly)  
  
Now, format the first partition in FAT format:  
  
sudo mkfs.vfat -F 32 /dev/mmcblk0p1 -n boot  
  
Remove the card and insert it again. It should automatically be mounted
on '/media/$USER/boot'.'

Comment: So I can create a new disk label with gparted

Comment: OK, that's progress. Can you now try your aforementioned commands now?

Comment: I figured out my problem. When using sfdisk I had typed sudo sfdisk /dev/sde1 << EOF. sde1 was just the partition which is why it was failing. I had to type sudo sfdisk /dev/sde << EOF. Thanks for your patience and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `sfdisk` I had typed `sudo sfdisk /dev/sde1 << EOF`. `sde1` was just the partition which is why it was failing. I had to type `sudo sfdisk /dev/**sde** << EOF`.